# Cannot generate TFRecords

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I followed [this](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py) tutorial and I did everything pretty much exactly as is done here but I am getting this error when running the generate_tfrecords file

```
File "generate_tfrecords.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecords.py", line 100, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecords.py", line 89, in create_tf_example
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\dataset_util.py", line 26, in 
int64_list_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 535, 
in init
    copy.extend(field_value)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 281, in 
extend
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\containers.py", line 281, in 
<listcomp>
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\type_checkers.py", line 138, in 
CheckValue
    raise TypeError(message)
TypeError: None has type <class 'NoneType'>, but expected one of: (<class 'int'>,)
```

Comment: please share the code you have written.

Comment: Most probably as the error says, `classes` is empty but it is looking for `int` type values. So, you might want to check the values coming from `classes`.